# Frame won't get destroyed before function executes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get a Tkinter canvas. (save it as an image using the PIL library)
I have a button inside a frame that runs the function below.

I want to destroy the frame right before it saves the canvas but I can't figure out how to do it.

here is what I've tried so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageGrab

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root,width=root.winfo_screenwidth(),height=root.winfo_screenheight(), bg="white",highlightthickness=0,cursor='dot')
canvas.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

save_canvas_frame = Frame(root,width=84,height=root.winfo_screenheight(),bg="#EFEFEF")
save_canvas_frame.place(x=0,y=0)

def save():

   # Close the frame <---
   save_canvas_frame.destroy()

   # Run the rest of the function <---
   x=root.winfo_rootx()+canvas.winfo_x()
   y=root.winfo_rooty()+canvas.winfo_y()
   x1=x+canvas.winfo_width()
   y1=y+canvas.winfo_height()   
   pic = ImageGrab.grab((x, y, x1, y1))
   pic.save("pic.png")

save_button = Button(save_canvas_frame,text="Save Canvas",command=save)
save_button.place(x=0,y=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Judging from the provided code, it should ideally work

Comment: I know, That is why I am so confused.
I thought maybe someone here may know how to solve it

Comment: Is your code short? Then paste the whole code here

Comment: Try calling `root.update()` after `save_canvas_frame.destroy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create 2 functions and call one by `.after()`:

```
def save_img():
   x=canvas.winfo_x()
   y=canvas.winfo_y()
   
   x1=x+canvas.winfo_width()
   y1=y+canvas.winfo_height()   
   print(x,y,x1,y1)
   pic= ImageGrab.grab((x, y, x1, y1))
   pic.save("pic.png")


def save():
   # Close the frame
   
   save_canvas_frame.destroy()
   root.after(1,save_img)
```